# Laravel 5 environment config arrays?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 4, you could set an environment based config folder structure:

```
/config/app.php
/config/dev/app.php
/config/staging/app.php
/config/testing/app.php
```

Can you do this with Laravel 5? I understand the `.env` concept and I'm using that to define which environment I'm in. But I need to define a config value that is an array of arbitrary length, and you can't do that with `.env` files.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if (in_array($request->input('value'), config('app.valid_values')) {
  // do something
}
```

This `valid_values` is simply an array of values. It's of arbitrary length, so you can't just set them in your `.env` file like:

```
VALID_VALUE1=...
VALID_VALUE2=...
etc.
```

AND the array needs to be different for each environment.

This was easy to do in Laravel 4 with environment configuration folders. But how do you do this with Laravel 5?

Comment: Future readers upgrading from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5 may be interested in [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com). It's a service that automates the upgrade process and provides custom feedback based on your specific project. *Disclaimer: I created Shift*.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you need to create an array on values, you can create on string format and when you need you can parse them

```
MY_ARRAY_VALUE=1,2,house,cat,34234
```

When you need them

```
$myArrayValue  = explode(',', env('MY_ARRAY_VALUE'));
```

Or save your values in JSON and get them with `json_decode()`

```
$myArrayValue  = json_decode(env('MY_ARRAY_VALUE'), true);
```

**Extra info:**

On Laravel 5, you need to translate all your configs files in one .env file.

On each environment your `.env` file will be diferent with values for this environment.

To set your environment, you need to change the value of `APP_ENV` in your `.env` file

```
APP_ENV=local
```

And you can create your own variables in that file

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration

This is an extract of the upgrade guide to Laravel 5.0
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.0

> Instead of a variety of confusing, nested environment configuration directories, Laravel 5 now utilizes DotEnv by Vance Lucas. This library provides a super simple way to manage your environment configuration, and makes environment detection in Laravel 5 a breeze. For more details, check out the full configuration documentation.

You can find a default `.env` file here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

> It is often helpful to have different configuration values based on the environment the application is running in. For example, you may wish to use a different cache driver locally than you do on your production server. It's easy using environment based configuration.
>
> To make this a cinch, Laravel utilizes the DotEnv PHP library by Vance Lucas. In a fresh Laravel installation, the root directory of your application will contain a .env.example file. If you install Laravel via Composer, this file will automatically be renamed to .env. Otherwise, you should rename the file manually.

Answer (score 9):

## Generally for Phpdotenv

Phpdotenv is about storing values in environment, not general purpose config library. Environment is UNIX concept and the values are always interpreted as character strings. Converting to different datatypes such as arrays or booleans even though convenient would be outside the scope of this class.

## Laravel config system

Laravel's config system is already separated. phpdotenv does environment, laravel does config. Then once config is done, environment is ignored. The concern of parsing environment variables from strings into whatever is passed on to laravel (weather that be their env function, or exploding inside your config files).

## Good practice

In other words, use Config::get() to get a specific conf file with your desired structure and you have what you need.

You should never use env() in the code directly when it is outside of the config folder according to the Laravel guidelines. It's a good practice to use config(). In config files use env() to get the data from .env file.

Comment: Further to this, the _reason_ you should only use `env()` in config files is because once you put your app into production you run `php artisan config:cache` and that resolves all of the config files to a cached text-only version which resolves all of your `env()` calls to text. the `env()` function is not available in a production environment and should (mainly) be used only to set up your config.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_map('trim', array_filter(explode(',', env('ARRAY_VALUE'))))
```

This will trim and also prevent to have empty items in the result array when env is empty string or has extra comma.