# Setting an array as the value of an environment variable in apache config file

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I am using apache config files to set environment variables like DBPASS in the following example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName project.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project
    SetEnv DBPASS "softwaredeveloper"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/project">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I use `getenv` in PHP to get the value og the variable like this:

```
$pass = getenv("DBPASS")
```

Is there a way to save arrays as environment variables in apache config file? I'd like to get a value like this in PHP:

```
[
"DBPASS" => "softwaredeveloper",
"LOG_CONFIG" => [
            "LOG_FILE"          => "/var/log/project/actions.log",
            "DELIMITER"         => ",",
            "DATE_FORMAT"       => "d.m.Y H:i:s",
            "SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y"
        ]
]
```

How should I add `LOG_CONFIG` variable to apache config?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I am not 100%. Searching on SO here throws up a few alternative approaches, including [exploding comma-delimited strings and decoding JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932031/laravel-5-environment-config-arrays) but I think I'd personally prefer the simple approach even if it's a bit more repetitive, like `LOG_CONFIG_FILE`, `LOG_CONFIG_DELIMITER` etc. It also makes it easier to change values individually, which may be important at some point.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that calling [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) without a varname argument will return all defined environmental variables as an associative array, which should at least make it easier to pull these values into your script, rather than a bunch of `getenv()` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's reasonable to assume that a valid environmental variable must be a key value pair of strings, and cannot represent a more complex data structure such as an array or object - to the best of my knowledge this is the case.

In any case, it is worth noting that when [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) is called with a varname argument, the type of the value returned will either be a `string` when the varname exists, or `false` where the varname does not exist.

From the PHP docs:

```
string getenv ( string $varname [, bool $local_only = FALSE ] )
```

If you search other similar questions on Stack Overflow, you will find several creative workarounds that suggest converting the desired structure into a format that can be represented as a string and then decoded when imported into the script - such as a comma-delimited string of values or JSON encoded object.

For example, let's assume you created the following environmental variable:

```
export DB_CONFIG='{"DB_NAME": "foo", "DB_PASSWORD": "bar"}'
```

You could import and decode it into a PHP associative array, like so:

```
$dbConfig = json_decode(getenv('DB_CONFIG'), true);
```

This would work but I feel that it does have trade-offs that are worth considering, versus setting environmental variables individually. It may or may not be important depending on your use-case, but you lose the ability to add, change or delete environmental variables independently of others.

For example, you might want to periodically update a database password but retain the same hostname and username.

It's certainly easier to update the value of `DB_PASSWORD` than recreate the data structure, re-encode it as a string and then update. In the latter case you will need to make sure that the change you made is both structurally and syntactically correct.

Therefore, although somewhat repetitive, I'd argue that the setting individual values is the simplest and clearest approach:

```
export LOG_CONFIG_FILE="/var/log/project/actions.log"
export LOG_CONFIG_DELIMITER=","
export LOG_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT="d.m.Y H:i:s"
export LOG_CONFIG_SHORT_DATE_FORMAT="d.m.Y"
# etc.
```

And, although a personal opinion, I feel that keeping your configuration as straightforward as possible is beneficial.

Finally, if you want to avoid the repetition of calling `getenv()` a multitude of times to import all the environmental variables you require, it is worth noting that when you call `getenv()` with no arguments, it returns all defined environmental variables as an associative array:

```
$dbConfig = getenv(); // associative array
$dbPassword = $dbConfig['DB_PASSWORD'];
```

P.S: If you absolutely require additional structure in your configuration it is worth nothing that [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) can  perform some limited parsing of configuration structure and type but this obviously means that you must store your configuration in .ini files.