# Get env variables names by matching text

Tags: php, laravel

I have some variables with matching names in .env file as below

```
    MY_SITE_01=http://www.google.com
    MY_SITE_02=http://www.facebook.com
    MY_SITE_03=http://www.twitter.com
```

Currently to get the value  am using

```
    env('MY_SITE_01')
    env('MY_SITE_02')
    env('MY_SITE_03')
```

Is there a way I can do it dynamically or just passing MY_SITE and it gets me all the full names of the variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 environment config arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932031/laravel-5-environment-config-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve your problem, you can store comma separated websites url into single env variable like shown below :

```
MY_SITES=http://www.google.com,http://www.facebook.com,http://www.twitter.com
```

When you need to retrieve its value, you can do :

```
$mySites  = explode(',', env('MY_SITES'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `my_site.php` file and place it in `config` folder and in the file you could return the data as:

```
<?php

return [
    'MY_SITE' => [
        'http://www.google.com',
        'http://www.facebook.com',
        'http://www.twitter.com'
    ]
];
```

Then in your controller or anywhere else you would like, you could use the [config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration) helper to retrieve the values.

```
print_r(config('my_site.MY_SITE'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those environments to `config/app.php` as,

```
'MY_SITES' => [
    'MY_SITE_01' => env('MY_SITE_01', 'http://www.google.com'),
    'MY_SITE_02' => env('MY_SITE_02', 'http://www.facebook.com'),
    'MY_SITE_03' => env('MY_SITE_03', 'http://www.twitter.com')
]
```

And get it by,

```
print_r(config('app.MY_SITES'));
```

This will get value from `.env` file so no more need to manage multiple places.