# How to Configure multiple emails in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

How do I use multiple from email configurations in my laravel app?

- Scenario#1: I want to use sales@mywebsite.com email for all billing related emails
- Scenario#2: I want to use support@mywebsite.com email for all notifications and other scenarios.

Question: in .env file we can configure only one email smtp details. How can I use multiple emails accounts and use their credentials for different scenarios.

My .env smtp setting

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=sales@mywebsite.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Sales"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Below sends email but picks up configuration from .env file.

```
\Mail::to($firmAdminEmail->admin_email)->send(new AdminLeadAccept($acceptLink));
```

Comment: Do not close the question as it is correctly explained...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#using-the-from-method) does not help, then I think you should have your `.env` with each config like:

- `MAIL_SALES_USERNAME`, `MAIL_SALES_PASSWORD`
- `MAIL_SUPPORT_USERNAME`, `MAIL_SUPPORT_PASSWORD`

Then in the config you have [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/a36f02c4f2c5617bfe355709ca1955884b11e2d3/config/mail.php#L36-L81), so you can add new "senders" inside `mailers` like this:

```php
'sales' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_SALES_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_SALES_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
],
'support' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_SUPPORT_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_SUPPORT_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => null,
    'auth_mode' => null,
],
```

So, before you send the email, you just select/change who you want to use as the sender:

```php
Mail::mailer('support')
    ->to($request->user())
    ->send(new SupportTicketGenerated($ticket));

// Or

Mail::mailer('sales')
    ->to($request->user())
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Read this part of the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail-via-a-specific-mailer) about `mailer`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have hardcoded emails in **.env**, you can keep them there like this:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="email@gmail.com"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESSES="email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com,email3@gmail.com"
```

In `config/mail.php` add some property like:

```
'from' => [
    'addresses' => explode(',', env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESSES')),
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
],
```

Refresh Laravel caches. Just run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Use them anywhere in your app like this:

```
config('mail.from.addresses')
```

That's it. Just note that .env is actually for storing string data. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57902771/7574023) might be interesting for you as well.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to send email from different email addresses depending on your app logic, you can do something like this.

Let's assume you have "roles" table for users, and each user have some specific "alias" field. As I don't know the whole logic of your app, you could change this as you want, but the simple way to get the problem solved you can use associated-array approach:

Add 'aliases' property in `mail.php`:

```
'from' => [
    'aliases' => [
        // all the roles values (starting from 0)
        'admin' => 0,
        'moderator' => 1,
        // ...
    ],
    'addresses' => explode(',', env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESSES')),
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'),
],
```

Again, don't forget to clear caches and use email sending like this:

```
// for example here the app will send email dynamically depending from auth user
// assume the $user is auth user (admin, moderator or something like that)
$alias_number = config('mail.from.aliases.' . $user->role->alias);
\Mail::from(config('mail.from.addresses')[$alias_number])
    ->to('some.email@gmail.com')
    ->send(new AdminLeadAccept($acceptLink));
```

You can override or change as you want. The core logic is that you can keep some string data in **.env** and extract from there dynamically.

Comment: question is how do I use multiple email configs. I want to use multiple emails sending smtp settings to use in different scenarios. Thanks

Comment: The user wants to send an email from a different mail depending a logic, not from multiple senders or addresses.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Downvote this if you want, but the initial question was much different and was edited many times, and now I see the new details in the question. Anyways, I've added some UPDATED stuff. This is just one way for your problem, you can change anything you want. For more dynamic apps, you would have more difficult DB structure, and you can improve the logic.

Comment: I didn't down-vote the answer, but this solution isn't clean
You shouldn't need to further process any values inside `.env` files